# Assistance with my Java AndroidOS Game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently trying to make a game on the Android OS using libGDX and I am working on a screen manager for it. I am basing this off a Screen Manager I use in VB.NET and trying to convert it over to java. Here is what I have so far and I will tell you what my exact problem is.

Manager.java

```
package rawct.gamename.Screen;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

    import rawct.gamename.GameName;
    import rawct.gamename.Screen.Screens.*;

    public class Manager extends GameName {
    private static List<Screen> Screens = new ArrayList<Screen>();
    private static List<Screen> NewScreens = new ArrayList<Screen>();
    private Screen Debug = new Debug("Debug");

    public Manager() {
        //Gdx.app.log("Manager", "New Instance!");
        AddScreen(Debug);
        //Testing to see which screens were loaded and testing unload
        UnloadScreen();
    }

    public void AddScreen(Screen NewScreen){
        NewScreens.add(NewScreen);
    }

    public void Draw(){ 
    }

    public void UnloadScreen(){
        Gdx.app.log("UnloadScreen", "Start");
        for(Iterator<Screen> s = NewScreens.iterator(); s.hasNext();){
            Gdx.app.log("Screen", ""+s.next().Name);
            //Should output Debug.Name but isn't, outputting Screen.Name
        }
        Gdx.app.log("UnloadScreen", "End");
    }

    public void Update(){
    }
}
```

Screen.java

```
package rawct.gamename.Screen;

public interface Screen {
    enum ScreenState {
        Active,
        Hidden,
        ShutDown
    }

    public static String Name = null;
    public ScreenState State = ScreenState.Active;
    public float Position = 0;
    public boolean Focused = false;
    public boolean GrabFocus = true;

    public void HandleInput();
    public void Update();
    public void Draw();
    public void Unload();
}
```

and My Test Screen

Debug.java

```
package rawct.gamename.Screen.Screens;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

import rawct.gamename.Screen.Screen;

public class Debug implements Screen {
    public Debug(String sName){
        // TODO Constructor
        Gdx.app.log("Debug", "New Instance!");
        Name = sName;
        //Won't let me set name, says "The final sfield Screen.Name cannot be assigned"
    }

    @Override
    public void HandleInput() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void Update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void Draw() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void Unload() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Okay now that I have posted all the code, what I am trying to do is access each .Name variable for each screen I will be adding to the List of Screens(List) but it is not letting me set/access my screens the way I want to. But it works in VB.NET I know that doesn't mean much but was just wondering how I can accomplish this in Java.

I want to be able to add new screens to the list of screens and give them names and access each of the methods and variables in each screen using a list.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to access the Screens using a key as in a HashMap?

Comment: where are you implementing the Screen interface? Are you passing the concrete screen objects in AddScreen() ?

Comment: A key as in being the name of the screen yes. I just want to be able to access the screens variables and methods that I add to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in an interface are static and final by default.
Remove all the variables in Screen interface.

Make `Screen`, a concrete class, have private variables and generate getters and setters to it.

Comment: Okay, I have removed them and set them inside the Debug.java file but how do I access those variables from that screen?

Comment: First, make Screen class concrete by declaring it as `public class Screen {`.

Comment: Once you make it concrete, you can use the setters of Screen instance to set values to the variables and getter methods to access those values. This is all you want, I suppose.

Comment: OMG! That was so simple, not sure why I was making it over complicated! Thanks so much!